# Генерация HTML списка определений в многомерном массиве Java

Tags: java, html, массивы, строки

Всем привет!
В данный момент я решаю следующую задачу:
нужно реализовать публичный статический метод **buildDefinitionList()**, который генерирует **HTML список определений** (теги `<dl>`, `<dt>` и `<dd>`) и возвращает получившуюся строку. При отсутствии элементов в массиве метод возвращает пустую строку.

Метод принимает на вход список определения в виде двумерного массива:

```
String[][] definitions = {

  {"definition1", "description1"},

  {"definition2", "description2"},

};
```

То есть каждый элемент входного массива сам является массивом, содержащим два элемента: термин и его определение.

```
String[][] definitions = {

  {"Блямба", "Выпуклость, утолщения на поверхности чего-либо"},

  {"Бобр", "Животное из отряда грызунов"},

};

 HtmlBuilder.buildDefinitionList(definitions);

// "<dl><dt>Блямба</dt><dd>Выпуклость, утолщение на поверхности чего-либо</dd><dt>Бобр</dt><dd>Животное из отряда грызунов</dd></dl>";
```

**Мой код:**

```
package com.arrays.problem6;

public class HtmlBuilder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            }

    public static String buildDefinitionList(String[][] definitions){
        var result = new StringBuilder();
        result.append("<dl><dt>");
        
        for (var item : definitions) {
            // append дополняет строку
            result.append("<dd>");
            //  result.append("<dd>");
            result.append(item);
            result.append("</dl></dd>");
        }
        result.append("</dl></dd>");

        // toString собирает все части в одну строку
        System.out.println(result);
        return result.toString();

    }

}
```

Программа работает в правильном направлении,но нужен вывод типа `<dl><dt>key</dt><dd>value</dd><dt>key2</dt><dd>value2</dd></dl>`, а у меня получается `<dl><dt><dd>[Ljava.lang.String;@59ad9541</dl></dd><dd>[Ljava.lang.String;@42d1de3c</dl></dd></dd></dl>`. Помогите найти мне ошибку, пожалуйста

Comment: А в чём проблема-то — просто найти ошибку или исправить какой-то недочёт? Мб приведёте пример, почему программа не работает, что она выводит?

Comment: @4500zenja , нужен вывод типа ```"<dl><dt>key</dt><dd>value</dd><dt>key2</dt><dd>value2</dd></dl>"``` ,а у меня получается ```"<dl><dt><dd>[Ljava.lang.String;@59ad9541</dl></dd><dd>[Ljava.lang.String;@42d1de3c</dl></dd></dd></dl>"```

Comment: [Ljava.lang.String;@42d1de3c - строковое представление массива, который и представляет пару `dt`, `dd`, а получаешь ты его из `item`. добавив ещё один цикл для `item` - получим уже строки. так же формируется неправильно `html`код - внутрри одного `dl` должно быть несколько пар `dt`, `dd`.

Comment: ну и на заметку, `dl` - [HTML element represents a description list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl) . description а не definition

Answer (score 0):

Все-таки пришлось разобраться самостоятельно.Вложенные циклы мне не потребовались.Все дело в создании двух дополнительных строковых переменных,которые записываются в двумерный массив.Ну и еще потребовалась та самая проверка на отсутствие элементов в массиве.

```
public class HtmlBuilder {

  public static void main(String[] args){
   }
   
    public static String buildDefinitionList(String[][] definitions){
        if(definitions.length==0){
            return "";
        }
        
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        result.append("<dl>");
        for(String[] definition : definitions){
            String name=definition[0];
            String description=definition[1];

            result.append("<dt>");
            result.append(name);
            result.append("</dt>");

            result.append("<dd>");
            result.append(description);
            result.append("</dd>");
        }
        result.append("</dl>");
        
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```